# Simple apache rewrite rule for magento search

Tags: apache, magento, url-rewriting, rule

I have a magento controller that performs a custom search. The url looks like:

```
mysite.com/catalogsearch/search?carbrand=toyota&color=red
```

I'm trying to rewrite this using apache rewrite rule to look like

```
mysite.com/catalogsearch/search/carbrand/toyota/color/red
```

I tried the following but the rule does not seem to work, takes me to 404 page:

```
RewriteRule /catalogsearch/search/cartype/(.*)/color/(.*)$ /catalogsearch/search/?cartype=$1&color=$2 [QSA]
```

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately catalogsearch module does not contain the controller search ,and then if you use the url: `mysite.com/catalogsearch/search?carbrand=toyota&color=red` in the URL rewrites you will always show 404 error page.

Please use `mysite.com/catalogsearch/result` or `mysite.com/catalogsearch/advanced` instead of `mysite.com/catalogsearch/search` .

Comment: The search?carbrand=toyota&color=red url does not show 404 error. The first url that I specified works because I use a custom search controller.